# Error when using knit/markdown: bkm [name of chunk] should only contain alphanumeric characters?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Unfortunately I can't produce a code for this error since it has arisen without change of code in a huge .rmd file of mine.

When trying to knit the document with markdown, which has previously worked flawlessly, I get this error:

> Error: bkm [name of chunk] should only contain alphanumeric characters, ':', '-' and '_'.
> Execution halted

Does anyone know already the cause of this, or what bkm stands for, which could assist me in finding the true reason for the error?

Best regards

Comment: Have you managed to work out which code chunk it relates to and what its name is? In general I have found huge rmd files sometimes act strangely and it is difficult to isolate the problem. I prefer to split up a large file into several smaller files as discussed [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html).

Comment: I assume that in naming a chunk, in labelling section, tables, equations or figures you used a character that markdown doesn't like. But as @Sam already said, you probably need to split it into pieces (or comment some parts out and try to find the error in the tideous way).

Comment: this started erroring out for me when I changed the output of a qmd from html to docx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you @SamR and @Julian for your kind replies. I did split the file into several pieces, and eventually the solution was to not include spaces in the chunk names, ie:

```
'''{r Name_of_cunk, eval=T, include=T, echo=F}
'''
```

Instead of

```
'''{r Name of cunk, eval=T, include=T, echo=F}
'''
```

This is only true for chunks that include Tables created using the package table1.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you for this. I was also puzzled by this error in my long script, even though it was already split in several files. In my case, space characters weren't the problem, but periods were. I replaced the periods with underscores in the chunk names and that solved the issue! Another similarity: it only created a problems for chunks including tables creating through the flextable package.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've also been struggling with this in quarto. I don't get why it takes until the chunk is run to pick up the error. It's taken a lot of time to debug!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by removing mathematical signs from the label of the table.